# Python is writing empty lists from cvs file DictReader data in Python 3.10

Tags: python, numpy, csv, iterator

So I have written this piece of code which is meant to read a csv file and write the data to a dictionary with keys "key1" "key2" "key3" "key4" with values given as a list comprised of data from columns of the csv file but with some modifications:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
#code
...
#code       
 with open(file,'r') as fl:
        csv_file=csv.DictReader(fl)
        fdata={
        'key1':[data['THING'] for data in csv_file],
        'key2':[f"{data['STR1']}, {data['STR2']}, {data['STR3']}" for data in csv_file],
        'key3':[np.array([data['FL1'],data['FL2']],dtype=float) for data in csv_file],
        'key4':[int(data['POPULATION']) for data in csv_file]
        }
```

The problem is that all the list come up empty except for the fist one, the one with key value "key1" and even when take out the typecast in "key4" it does not work, initially i thought it had to do with numpy, type casting or the string formatting but I don't what is wrong, online there are a lot of examples like this and using print() debugging shows that the data is being read. I don't know what to do here.

Also I'm certain the keys for the csv file "THING", "STR1", "STR2", "STR3", "FL1", "FL2" are correct. Another thing is that the csv file is large but not millions of rows long,

Comment: csv_file is an iterator, not a list.  It can only be iterated once.  After that, it's empty.

Comment: Thank you. So i need to open it multiple times? or do I write a list with dicts? what do you recomend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's to do with how your `csv.DictReader` object is being iterated over. When you do a list comprehension over the csv_file object for `key1`, you exhaust the iterator. This means that when you try to do the list comprehension for `key2`, there's no data left in `csv_file` to iterate over, and so on for the subsequent keys.

Instead, try reading the CSV data into a list first, and then perform your list comprehensions on this list.

Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

with open(file, 'r') as fl:
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(fl)
    all_data = list(csv_file)

fdata = {
    'key1': [data['THING'] for data in all_data],
    'key2': [f"{data['STR1']}, {data['STR2']}, {data['STR3']}" for data in all_data],
    'key3': [np.array([data['FL1'], data['FL2']], dtype=float) for data in all_data],
    'key4': [int(data['POPULATION']) for data in all_data]
}
```

By storing all the rows in all_data first, you ensure that you can iterate over the rows multiple times without exhausting the iterator.